# Chrome CSS Hack and Media Queries

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to make a responsive site, but my attempt so far has some problems in chrome. The problem now - insert media queries into the chrome css hack?

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 

#myid {position: absolute; top: 10px;}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

#myid {position: absolute; top: 8px;}

}

}
```

Need it only in css, so no javascript or php. Anyone an idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: wow, you are welcome!!! Thx for your very expert answer.... Do you really think i havent try it already to solve the problem with chrome? Why i would ask here...

Comment: Ask about your problem, not about [your attempt to solve your problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). By the way, you can't nest media queries like that. However, you could combine the hack media query and the other media query into one...

Comment: What exactly are your problems?

Comment: I´ve added a font via @font-face which is rendered differently in chrome and ie. All line-heights was "destroyed" so i used the hack. The problem is now the responsive site combined with hacks and media queries.

Comment: @Alex: smart alec comments won't get people to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer you want to hear, and that I hinted at in a comment, is:

```css
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    #myid {position: absolute; top: 10px;}
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #myid {position: absolute; top: 8px;}
}​
```

As much as I'd like to solve your underlying problem...

> I´ve added a font via @font-face which is rendered differently in
>   chrome and ie. All line-heights was "destroyed" so i used the hack.

?!

Comment: This media query is unfortunately now also targeting Firefox.

Comment: @ShashankBhatt: There's nothing unfortunate about it, that was a decision made with great care. See these Firefox bugs [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1176968) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1444139). You shouldn't need a "Chrome only CSS hack" in 2020. Just like I asked the guy back in 2012... What's your underlying problem? Why do you need this?

Comment: @thirtydots I need this because icon alignment is not exactly in round center only for chrome and in FF, it shows centered. i already used all centering methods so far from css and i am not saying for vertical but problem is with horizontal centering. there is only 1px issue but my tester is giving that to me.